# PHP 7 vs Java 8 Performance

Tags: java-8, php-7

Has anyone tested PHP7 vs Java 8, I was wondering about their performance and how they compare. I was thinking the new virtual machine introduced for PHP was still new or immature compared to Java 8 and its new garbage collector. Not sure about it though

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Comparing PHP and Java is apples and oranges.  It is hard to get a fair and meaningful comparison.

However, see http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=java&lang2=php.  The short answer is that Java 8 is faster than PHP 7.  But you should read all of the caveats on the page ... including the fact that language vs language benchmarks are pretty bogus.

For the record, this is what that page currently says (2017-04-23):

> Java programs versus PHP
>
> all other Java programs & measurements by benchmark task performance
>
> ```
> fasta secs    mem     gz  cpu     cpu load
> Java: 2.13    36,036  2457    5.66    94% 58% 59% 60%
> PHP:  59.37   8,896   1030    59.36   5% 2% 3% 100% 
>
> fannkuch-redux     secs   mem     gz  cpu     cpu load 
> Java: 13.74   30,368  1282    54.12   100% 98% 98% 99%  
> PHP:  280.04  33,588  1150    1,117.48    100% 100% 100% 100%
>
> mandelbrot     secs   mem     gz  cpu     cpu load  
> Java: 7.10    90,588  796     27.92   99% 99% 98% 98%  
> PHP:  125.17  136,776     863     499.16  100% 100% 100% 100% 
>
> n-body     secs   mem     gz  cpu     cpu load  
> Java: 21.54   27,092  1489    21.56   1% 1% 100% 1%  
> PHP:  358.21  8,668   1082    358.12  17% 0% 1% 83% 
>
> spectral-norm      secs   mem     gz  cpu     cpu load  
> Java: 4.29    29,884  950     16.56   96% 97% 99% 95%  
> PHP:  37.94   19,420  1135    150.67  99% 99% 100% 99% 
>
> binary-trees   secs   mem     gz  cpu     cpu load  
> Java: 11.26   593,156     835     39.02   85% 88% 90% 88%  
> PHP:  88.07   736,372     1027    247.49  92% 77% 23% 91% 
>
> k-nucleotide   secs   mem     gz  cpu     cpu load  
> Java: 7.93    465,372     1802    25.11   75% 75% 75% 93%  
> PHP:  43.96   235,632     1060    142.28  87% 100% 71% 72% 
>
> reverse-complement     secs   mem     gz  cpu     cpu load 
> Java: 1.10    345,352     1661    2.40    33% 82% 53% 54% 
> PHP:  2.81    135,124     426     1.75    31% 21% 44% 57% 
>
> pidigits   secs   mem     gz  cpu     cpu load 
> Java: 3.06    31,760  938     3.16    6% 3% 97% 1%  
> PHP:  2.15    9,884   394     2.15    1% 0% 100% 1% 
>
> regex-redux    secs   mem     gz  cpu     cpu load  
> Java: 12.31   902,528     929     38.75   73% 76% 86% 81%  
> PHP:  3.34    158,792     786     3.30    25% 26% 22% 92%
> ```
>
> Java Version
>
> ```
> java version "1.8.0_121" 
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
> ```
>
> PHP Version
>
> ```
> PHP 7.1.4 (cli) (built: Apr 16 2017 16:17:54) ( NTS ) 
> Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.1.0, 
> Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
> ```